# Unable to create project in android studio after updating to latest version

Tags: android, gradle, build, project

I have updated android studio to latest version 2.3 a week back. After so much research I'm somehow able to fix gradle build.But now android studio is not creating new projcects.It is stuck at gradle build for project.I've waited for almost 1 hour.It was at the same point.I updated the gradle to the latest version 3.4.1 but I dont know why I'm getting this error.Its not even showing any error.
Someone please help me...Thaks a lot in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your SDK especially build tool and extras.

Delete temp files of system.

After that restart your system and android studio and create new a new project and wait until it completely build(may be it take some time more than it's usual time, but it happen first time only, so have patience).

Hope this will resolve issue.

If still you have same problem; re-install your Android studio.

Comment: Thanks a lot man..I did exactly what you said and it worked like a charm